# Returning a dictionary based on a condition

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to use a lambda or other python feature to return an dictionary if a condition is met, or none if not.

```
myDict = None

myDict = lambda c: {} if not myDict else myDict
```

Clearly, this not work, since lambda is not executed, so that what will be most "pythonic" way to do it?

Comment: Empty dict is `False`.

Comment: yes, but I want to update my dict after I mean myDic.update()

Comment: After the first line, `myDict` is `None`, after the second one it is a lambda function. It is never a dictionary.

Comment: The sentence "I want to return an Dictionary if there is and condition or none if not." is unclear to me.  Could you try to clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myDict = None
get_myDict = lambda: myDict or {}

get_myDict()
```

returns an empty dictionary.

Comment: I think the conditional expression is probably prefered to logical `or` these days.  (It behaves a little more naturally for beginners)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you should just use the conditional expression:

```
myDict = {} if not myDict else myDict
```

---

`lambda` is a way of creating *functions*.  So:

```
func = lambda x: x*x
```

is approximately the same as:

```
def func(x):
    return x*x
```

So, in your example, you create a *function* more or less equivalent to:

```
def myDict(c):
    return {} if not myDict else myDict
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `locals().get('myDict', None)` (or `globals().get` depending on your scope)